# Lizards Undergo Rapid Evolution: Please, tell me this is not a lie

Tags: evolution

[This article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/04/080417112433.htm) states that transition from eating insect to eating plants is called and caused evolution.
The article neither provides images nor swears that they are telling the truth.
Has someone else tried the same method as the article's author? Those lezards were still eating insects in nineties in Algeria.
Can somebody living in Pod Mrcaru provide us with images of the same lizards?
Could this transition which is preceeded by human [... not nature] be compared to evolution?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78233/discussion-on-question-by-whicard-lizards-undergo-rapid-evolution-please-tell).

Answer (score 3):

The article is referring to an actual series of [studies](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.0030-1299.2007.15989.x), the divergent evolution is caused by the population being introduced to a small island free of predators. It is [well known](https://www2.palomar.edu/anthro/synthetic/synth_5.htm) that small isolated populations can evolve quickly, change can spread much faster in small populations. Note the lizards still [eat insects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18344323) it is just the island population also eats some plants, they have other noticeable differences as well.

To answer your question **Yes this is evolution**, likely a combination of natural selection and genetic drift. Evolution is just a change in allele frequency (basically a heritable change) a group of organisms over time.

Like many news sites they do horrible job of sourcing their information, but is referring to actual science.

Comment: just to be clear, the comment in my answer does not refer to your answer but the one OP has marked.

Comment: [It is well known that small isolated ...] is this a law? I'm sorry it's not well known. [lizards still eat insects...] why wasn't this stated in the article? P.S answer me is this evolution?

Comment: Thank you John for your knowledge, time and energy. I'm accepting your reply as an alternative only because I trust you. I'll see and come back later. Thank you so much NatWH

Comment: @John In the well known link, (1) the author says "If you do it an infinite number of times, it will be 50%.". This is a fallacy, isn't it?

Comment: I can't find that anywhere in the paper, do you have a page number?

Answer (score 1):

Since the existing answer barely even tried, I will give one. Rapid adaptive evolution on ecological time-scales is pretty much non-controversial, and has basically been understood since Haldane. The paper that this report is derived from is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2290806/) (amongst others, see John's answer), and does appear to show morphological evolution over the course of some 37 years in response to different resource availability.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and your time.

Comment: In Fig. 4. of the article, how can I convince myself that this is evolution rather than a normal morphological change (e.g. between two persons)?

Comment: Fig. 4 is a demonstrative example; I would look at the quantitative evidence in the earlier figures.

Comment: I swear of God, I could not be convinced. I'm sorry for your time. I'm going have a look at https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01 and find some free glossaries

Comment: and please NatWH do not blame me. As you may admit, today's internet is full of lies. the Arabic article that targeted the object article was also full of (let say lies) falsification and information that neither exist in the object article nor in the official one you provided. I will study the article you provided. Here is the link http://www.ahewar.org/debat/show.art.asp?aid=346856